# Recursive regex in python regex module?

Tags: python, regex, recursion

I would like to capture all `[[A-Za-z].]+` in my string, that is, all repeats of a alphabetic character followed by a dot.

So for example, in `"ABC A.B.C. UVWX U.V.W.X. XYZ XY.Z."`

I would like to pull out `"A.B.C."` and  `"U.V.W.X."` only (as they are repeats of one character followed by a dot).

It seems almost that I need a recursive regex to do this `[[A-Za-z].]+`.

Is it possible to implement this with either python's `re` module or `regex` module?

Comment: I don't think recursion is the right word here. Repetition would be a better way to describe this idea accurately.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you, using simple re.findall notation:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))(?:[A-Za-z]\.)+
```

In the regex, I first check if it is the start of the string, or if there is a space before the string, and then i check for repetitive letter+period. I place the parts i do not want to capture into a non-capture group `(?:...)`

You can see it working here:
https://regex101.com/r/ZwW7c7/4

Python Code (that I wrote):

```
import re
regex = r"(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))(?:[A-Za-z]\.)+"
string = 'D.E.F. ABC A.B.C. UVWX U.V.W.X. XYZ XY.Z.'
print(re.findall(regex,string))
```

Output:

> ['D.E.F.', 'A.B.C.', 'U.V.W.X.']

Comment: This does not match leading `A.B.C.` out of `A.B.C XYZ`.

Comment: You are right, we need to check for \s or beginning of string, i will update!

Comment: You don't need increase `matchNum` by 1 manually. `enumerate` accepts optional `start` parameter: `enumerate(matches, 1)`

Comment: Code is auto-generated by regex101 :)

Comment: code is now updated to work for `A.B.C. ABC A.B.C. UVWX U.V.W.X. XYZ XY.Z.`. Output is `A.B.C.` `A.B.C.` `U.V.W.X.`

Comment: Thanks shawn, is there no way to do this without the `for` loops, i.e. just sticking to `re` syntax such as `re.findall`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non-capturing group to define your match, then group its repeats nested between boundary characters (in this case anything that's not a letter or a dot) and capture all matched groups:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->

import re

MATCH_GROUPS = re.compile(r"(?:[^a-z.]|^)((?:[a-z]\.)+)(?:[^a-z.]|$)", re.IGNORECASE)

your_string = "ABC A.B.C. UVWX U.V.W.X. XYZ XY.Z."  # get a list of matches

print(MATCH_GROUPS.findall(your_string))  # ['A.B.C.', 'U.V.W.X.']
```

A bit clunky but should get the job done with edge cases as well.

P.S. The above will match single occurrences as well (e.g. `A.` if it appears as standalone) if you're seeking for multiple repeats only, replace the `+` (one or more repeats) with a range of your choice (e.g. `{2,}` for two or more repeats).

edit: A small change to match beginning/end of string boundaries as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using [positive look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'(?:(?<=\s)|^)(?:[A-Za-z]\.)+(?:(?=\s)|$)'
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'ABC A.B.C. UVWX U.V.W.X. XYZ XY.Z.')
['A.B.C.', 'U.V.W.X.']
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'A.B.C. UVWX U.V.W.X. XYZ XY.Z.')
['A.B.C.', 'U.V.W.X.']
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'DEF A.B.C. UVWX U.V.W.X.Y')
['A.B.C.']
```

**UPDATE** As @bubblebobble suggested, you the regex could be simplified using `\S` (non-space character) with negative look-around assertions:

```
pattern = r'(?<!\S)(?:[A-Za-z]\.)+(?!\S)'
```

Comment: @bobblebubble, Thank you for the comment. I will update the answer to include your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to do the job (testing if we are on the beginning of the string or after a space) :

```
\A([A-Za-z]\.)+|(?<=\s)([A-Za-z]\.)+
```

EDIT : Sorry Shawn didn't see your modified answer